# Waypoints JS can't find variable

Tags: javascript

I am try to get waypoints js to work but I'm struggling some what. I keep getting the error :

> 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Waypoint'

I am using the no framework js file as im not using jquery.

Here is my current **markup** :

```
<section class="section" id="waypoint">
    <div class="inner">
        <h1>I am a heading</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Waypoints **source** files that i have included after the body tag :

```
<script src="js/waypoint.js"></script>
<script src="js/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

**Js** for waypoint :

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('waypoint'),
  handler: function() {
    notify('Basic waypoint triggered')
  }
});
```

Appreciate any advice to what i am missing here.

Comment: So you are including the library after executing your code?

Comment: Oh my days!! Its been a long day, thanks so much for pointing out such a daft mistake i made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script tags were round the wrong way, the code was executing before the library was loaded.